# unable to import weights.bin into react native using vscode

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, import, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to implement a model using TensorFlowJS,
I took an existing h5 model, and transferred it to json and weights
using tensorflowjs_wizard,
I'm now trying to import both files so I can use them, but my VS code does not recognize the weights file, even when I try to get the location by hand, it won't recognize the file [image]

anyone knows a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer,
in the root folder you need to create a metro.config.js file and add this:

```
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');

module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
  resolver: {
    assetExts: ['bin', 'txt', 'jpg', 'ttf', 'png'],
    sourceExts: ['js', 'json', 'ts', 'tsx', 'jsx'],
    blacklistRE: blacklist([/platform_node/])
  },
};
```